# using HanekeSwift image cache for Entire Application

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I'm making an application which downloads lot's of image on every ViewController . I'm trying to use HanekeSwift and I'm wondering that How should I use cache images on my different ViewController so it wouldn't need to download downloaded images again.

How can I make the cached image globally available in my entire application and not just inside a specific ViewController ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make it globally using image with key.cache image with some unique key for image.
`imageView.hnk_setImage(image, key: key)` and fetch image using

`let imageCache = Shared.imageCache
  imageCache.fetch(key: key).onSuccess { (image) in
      //set your image here
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data gathered either through core data or nsuserdefaults if the image cache is not too large (note nsuserdefaults mostly used for saving small things like user settings) Then write code to get saved data if available if not fetch data. [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)